# how to select a record which is present more than once in table

Tags: sql

i have a table like this:

```
book_no     lang      price      shelf     
----------  --------  ---------  -----
1           eng       20         a  
4           french    34         a  
2           eng       26         b  
7           russian   71         b  
12          german    33         a  
43          french    15         d  
11          eng       43         c  
14          rusian    33         a  
19          eng       20         d  
24          french    40         c  
23          eng       57         a  
27          russian   48         b  
42          german    31         c  
25          french    15         d
```

from this table i want to fetch book_no, language, shelf.
The languages which are present more than 3 times, only those books are to be shown.
I tried:

```
select book_no,lang,shelf from a where (count(lang)>3)
```

thanks for help in advance

Comment: SQL? Looks like HTML to me? :S

Comment: sorry I did not get that. Why does it looks like HTML ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT book_no, 
       lang, 
       shelf 
FROM   a 
WHERE  lang IN (SELECT lang 
                FROM   A 
                GROUP  BY lang 
                HAVING Count(*) > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

group functions like count, sum can't be used in a where clause.

Use a group by

```
group by book_no -- or the fields you need, depending on sgbd, you can put one or have to put all
```

and a having clause

```
Having count(lang) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports aggregate window functions, you could try this:

```
SELECT
  book_no,
  lang,
  shelf
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY lang) AS book_count
  FROM a
) s
WHERE book_count >= 3
```